# Количество известных остатков

Tags: массивы, pascal

Я написал программу. Она должна получать количество известных остатков (при делении), сами эти остатки (по очереди, один за одним), числа, при делении на которые эти остатки получаются (последовательно, один за одним). Задача проги - найти наименьшее положительное число, которое при делении на введённые числа даёт введённые остатки соответственно (т.е. первый остаток при делении на первое число, второй - на второе и т.д.), используя [китайскую теорему об остатках](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Китайская_теорема_об_остатках) и особый способ её решения, который описать будет сложно. Вот код:

```
Program A0xCHIN;    
type    
    TMas1=array [Byte] of Integer;    
    TMas2=array [Byte] of Integer;    
function GetMult (B: TMas2; N: Integer): Integer;    
    var    
        Y, G, I: Integer;    
    begin    
        Y:=B[1];    
        for I:=2 to N do    
        begin    
            G:=B[I];    
            Y:=Y*G;    
        end;    
        GetMult:=Y;    
    end;    
procedure GetRemainders (N: Integer; A: TMas1); {procedure writes remainders to TMas1}    
    var    
        I: Integer;    
        begin    
        for I:=1 to N do    
            begin    
                WriteLn ('Input a remainder ', I);    
                Read (A[I])    
            end;    
        end;    
procedure GetModules (N: Integer; B: TMas2); {procedure writes modules to TMas2}    
    var    
        I: Integer;    
    begin    
        for I:=1 to N do    
            begin    
                WriteLn ('Input a module ', I);    
                Read (B[I])    
            end;    
        end;    
function FindNum (A: TMas1; B: TMas2; N: Integer): LongInt; {function finds number}    
    var    
        I, X: Integer;    
        Result, Res, PRes: LongInt;    
        Label    
             startloop;    
    begin    
        X:=0;    
        PRes:=A[1];    
    for I:=1 to N do    
        begin    
        startloop:    
            if (((PRes+(X*GetMult (B, I)) - A[I]) mod B[I])=0)then    
                begin    
                    Res:=PRes+(X*GetMult (B, I));    
                    PRes:=PRes+(X*GetMult (B, I));    
                    X:=0    
                end    
            else    
                begin    
                    X:=X+1;    
                    {GoTo startloop;}    
                end;    
        Result:=Res;    
        FindNum:=Result    
        end;    
    end;    
var    
    N: Integer;    
    A: TMas1;    
    B: TMas2;    
begin    
    WriteLn ('Input number of remainders: ');    
    Read (N);    
    GetRemainders (N, A);    
    GetModules (N, B);    
    WriteLn ('Result is ', FindNum (A, B, N));    
    Write ('Press ENTER to exit');    
    ReadLn;    
end.
```

Компилятор у меня обычный, вот такой: [image]

Вопросы по этому:

- Программа присваивает PRes совсем не первый остаток, что я ввёл, а что-то другое. Почему?
- Подходят ли типы в объявлении массива для следующих функций: в массиве должно храниться до нескольких сотен целых неотрицательных чисел?
- Код:

  ```
  type
    TMas=array [1..10] of Integer;
  var
    A: TMas;
  ```

  Почему `a[1]=12`, а не что-то ещё?
- Что хранится в массиве на месте тех элементов, которым не задали значения?

Comment: Почему-то строчки не переводятся, хотя в предпросмотре переводились...

Comment: Нашёл, как эту прогу можно написать в 2 раза короче и нечестно. При вводе проверяем все модули или что-то там на взаимную простоту, потом пробегаем весь LongInt в поисках нужного числа. Быстро и халтурно!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли в параметрах функции указать `var` для переменных, которые должны быть возвращены через параметры:

```
procedure GetRemainders (N: Integer; var A: TMas1);

procedure GetModules (N: Integer; var B: TMas2);
```

На месте не заданных элементов может быть любая лабуда. Так как это паскаль, при создании массивов и т.п. "зверей" в программе, он не гарантирует, что они будут обнулены, поэтому, если это необходимо, делайте это самостоятельно.

И на вашем месте я бы пользовался списками, вместо массивов, это немного сложнее, но вы не будете сразу выделять память под массивы в сотни байт. Да и циклы у вас все без "завихрений" т.е. метод со списками весьма удобен. (имхо)

При этом:

```
TMas1=array [Byte] of Integer;
```

вы ограничены 256ю числами. Кроме того, при такой записи индексы начинаются с "0"
А также -32768 <= Integer <= 32767

Использование меток `goto` не комильфо.

Comment: Понятия не имею=) У меня в тетрадьке записано <МАССИВ>:=array [<ТИП_индекса>] of <ТИП_элементов>. Я понял, что тип индеска можно указывать не только как промежуток типа 1..10, но и как имя какого-то типа. Выходит, что в TMas1 и TMas2 должно быть 65 537 элементов (не более). Мне кажется, что с if/else я что-то напутал, потому что если я делаю такую проверку: остатки 2, 2, 3, 5, числа 9, 4, 5, 7, то по идее прога должна найти число 1 118, так как 1 118=2+0*9+1*9*4+6*9*4*5, и прога должна найти числа 0, 1, 6 самостоятельно. Но находит только 0 правильно.  Прогу я уже немного изменил.

Comment: Да можно использовать. И так и так и еще по-всякому. Читайте внимательно, что у вас не так.